# Fckeditor with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

How do I implement Fckeditor with Zend.

I have this on the view:

```
src="/js/fckeditor.js"></script>..etc..

<textarea name="profileDescription" id="ckeditor"..etc..

 window.onload = function()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('ckeditor')) {
            var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('ckeditor') ;
            oFCKeditor.BasePath = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>js/fckeditor.js";
            oFCKeditor.Height = 500;
            oFCKeditor.Width = 700;
            oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ;
        }
    };
```

I get this error:
Application error

Exception information:

Message: Resource 'js' not found

Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'js',
  'action' => 'fckeditor.jseditor',
  'module' => 'default',
  'InstanceName' => 'ckeditor',
  'Toolbar' => 'Default',
)
```

Comment: could you be more informative? where you plan to add ckeditor?

Comment: i couldn't find any ckeditor module for zend framework  if you have any please add infomattion. http://www.harikt.com/content/add-wysiwyg-ckeditor-zendtextarea-element-zendform might help

Comment: I think src must be /public/js/fckeditor.js (in 08/15 ZF Application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create the htaccess to read this kind of files!

This is my default htaccess to ZF projects:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

ServerSignature off

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Server
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag register_globals off
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /proj_rodrigo/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Maybe your htaccess is a little different like this part:

```
RewriteRule !\.(phtml|swf|jar|js)index.php
```

If this one is your format, just add JS to the () information inside.

Hope it works.
Regards